How to find "link-name" of a library after it's built with cmake?
I'm building a C++ project with CMakeLists.txt, that depends on some library, which is built in the build-process. I've used:
add_subdirectory(/path/to/some_lib)
that contains another CMakeLists.txt, that builds that library. In order to link I call:
target_link_libraries(${target} some_lib_name)
My question is:
how am I supposed to know what "some_lib_name" to use in target_link_libraries?
I've looked at the relevant pages in the cmake documentation and looked in the build directory, but there's too much info. My question isn't specific to some library, but general.

"how am I supposed to know what "some_lib_name" to use in target_link_libraries?" - Read documentation for the library which you use, or examine its CMakeLists.txt. There is no predefined name of the targets created by the subprojects.

Since your add_subdirectorying another CMake project, you can use it's target's names in target_link_libraries. But what those target names are is not correlated to anything else as a law. You need to read the project's docs. Or read/debug the CMakeLists.txt. Or list all targets via CMake configuration. Or read the generated buildsystem files. Or run a buildsystem-specific command to list all targets. Ex. for Ninja, you can run ninja -t targets in the build directory.
